# e Online source for alternative proofs

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra, number-theory, alternative-proof

I'm looking for some alternative proofs for various theorems. My goal is to compile a list of various proofs each relating to a specific theorem (such as the triangle inequality, Fermat's Little Theorem [a^p-1 = 1 mod p], euler's theorem, Cauchy-Schwarz Inequality, proof of sizes of infinity, etc.) I'm wondering if there is an online (or text) source for this, preferably with the original author of each proof where available. At the end of the day I'm not looking for a specific theorem but rather a source where I can type in "Minkowski's Theorem" or "Stokes Theorem" and get a variety of proofs.

To narrow this down (since this is fairly nebulous, I will admit), I'm taking an introductory (real) analysis course, undergraduate Abstract Algebra, and am studying Number Theory independently. The reason for my compiling this list is that for each new proof that I work through I get a better understanding not only of the theorem but also its role in mathematics.

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: I think you will have to be a bit more spesific than "Various theorems"

Comment: The book "Proofs from the book" has a compilation of several beautiful proofs in number theory, analysis, geometry and some other fields. For example it has 6 proofs for the infinity of primes. This might be what you are looking for. You can find a [copy of the first chapter here](http://www.emis.de/classics/Erdos/textpdf/aigzieg/aigzieg.pdf).

Comment: Thanks Winther, that is exactly the kind of thing I had in mind. I had come across this book a while ago and forgot the title!

Comment: For some theorems there is already a large compilation of different proofs online, e.g., for [quadratic reciprocity](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/1420/whats-the-best-proof-of-quadratic-reciprocity).

Answer (score 1):

I found a source - doesn't have multiple posts for all theorems but it's definitely in the vein of what I had in mind:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Main_Page